# Incorrect Output of ListPlot using PlotMarkers with text

Tags: plotting

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my code. I just want illustrate four columns consisted of different numbers as plot markers.

```
ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}},
PlotMarkers -> {"\[Pi]", "8", "9", "10", "2", "5", "3", "4", "1", 
"\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\)"}, Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {"Number of 
columns", "Size of the columns"}]
```

But I get this plot output:

[image]

Any help or a hint will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

UPDATE: I have figured out the wrong format of my code thanks to @Graumagier.

But, I have searched in google how to change the scale of the x-axis because automatically in the plot the coordinates with $x=1$ are very close to the y-axis. Is there any way to adjust that?

[image]

Comment: You'll at least need another set of `{}` for each of the one-element lists (`{{2, 1}}, {{2, 2}}, {{3, 1}}, {{3, 2}}, {{4, 1}}, {{4, 2}}`), otherwise `ListPlot` won't interpret them as points with two coordinates, but as lists of two points. And I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with `{1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: @Graumagier I want to write `{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4}` but followed an example here where uses different code:`ListPlot[{{1, 2, 3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 6, 9, 10}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 12}}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"\[Alpha]", "\[Beta]", "\[Gamma]"}]`

Comment: I see. You can do it this way, but you have to decide whether you want to plot a list of x values with automatic y values (e.g. `{1,2,3}` corresponding implicitly to `{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}`) or lists of points with explicit x and y coordinates (e.g. `{{1,2}}`), in which case you have to make sure to use the right (double) parentheses. You can mix those of course, but if you get duplicate points in the process you end up with overlaying labels like in your case.

Comment: @Graumagier The thing is that I don't know how to write it and all coordinates get the correspoding number as a plot marker. For example, I want {{4,1},{4,2}} points to be marked as "1" and "Sqrt(2)".

Comment: In this case you'd have to write `ListPlot[
 {{{4, 1}}, {{4, 2}}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"1", Sqrt[2]}
 ]`. Here's an example of mixed list formats, maybe that will make it clearer: `ListPlot[
 {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {{2, 1}}, {{3, 2},{3, 4}}},
 PlotMarkers -> {"1", Sqrt[2], "3"}
 ]`.

Comment: @Graumagier Thank you so much for your help. I got it to work.

Comment: @Graumagier - I would add your last comment to your answer

Comment: @eldo – You're absolutely right, I've added it.

Comment: Use `PlotRange-> {{0, 5}, Automatic}` to control the scale on the `x` axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**General information about list formats with `ListPlot`**

You have to make sure to use the right format for the lists of points. `ListPlot` takes three formats, as you can see in the [function's documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html?q=ListPlot):

Here you provide multiple y values which get assigned consecutive x values automatically by `ListPlot`. All the points are treated as belonging to the same dataset:

```
{y1, y2, …}
```

Here you provide multiple points with explicit x and y values. Each point is a list with two coordinates, and they get treated as points of the same dataset:

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, …}
```

Here you provide multiple lists with one or more points each. Each list of lists get treated as a separate dataset:

```
{{{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}}, {{x21, y21}, {x22, y22}}, …}
```

**Concerning your specific case**

The distinction between the last two is important in your case, because `ListPlot` loops over datasets in order to decide which `PlotMarkers` to assign to which points.

Here's an example of mixed list formats in order to plot (1) a number of y values with implicit x coordinates, (2) a single point with explicit x  and y coordinates and (3) a list of two points, each with explicit x and y coordinates. Each of these datasets gets a separate value in `PlotMarkers`:

```
ListPlot[
  {
    {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
    {{2, 1}},
    {{3, 2}, {3, 4}}
  },
  PlotMarkers -> {"1", Sqrt[2], "3"}
]
```

[image: ListPlot with multiple datasets, each with a unique plot marker.]